# Upload data and select them from two tables and display them in the same HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I would like to ask you how to select data from two different tables and display them in the single HTML table. I've tried many ways, but I can't find the right way.

[First table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMqKW.png)

[Second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klcnv.png)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="reg-area">
     <form action="upload.php" method="post" align="center" id="register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="username" minlength="5" maxlength="25" required/><br /><br />
        <input type="number" name="age" max="99" required/><br /><br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="r1" checked="checked">
        <label for="r1">Muž</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="r2">
        <label for="r2">Žena</label><br /><br />
        <input type="file" name="file_img" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload"/>
     </form>
    </div>
        <?php
            require_once('Db.php');         
            Db::connect('localhost', '***', '***', '***');

            if ($_POST)
            {   
        $existuje = Db::querySingle('
                  SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM table1
                  WHERE username=?
                  LIMIT 1
          ', $_POST['username']);
          if ($existuje)
                  die ('<p align="center" class="element-animation"><font color="red">Uživatel s touto přezdívkou již existuje.</font></p>');
        else

        /*INSERT USERNAME, age, gender into Table1 */

            $datum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                Db::query('
                    INSERT INTO table1 (username,   age, gender, date)  
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                ', $_POST['username'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['gender'], $datum); 
        header("location: index.php"); 
        }                              

        /*DISPLAY CONTENT OF BOTH TABLES*/

            $snapy = Db::queryAll('
                SELECT *
          FROM table1
          JOIN table2 ON `ID` = `img_ID`
          ORDER BY ID;
            ');
            echo('<div align="center" id="content"><h1>Seznam se s:</h1><table width="100%" cellspacing="10" collspacing="10"></div>');
        echo('<th>Username</th><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th><th>Uploaded image</th>');
            foreach ($snapy as $s)
            {
                echo('<tr align="center"><td>' . htmlspecialchars($s['username']));
                echo('</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($s['age']));
                echo('</td><td>' . '<img src="img/' . $s['gender'] .'.png' .'" width="25px"/>');
                echo('</td><td>' . '<img src="images/' . $filename . $filetype .'" width="25px"/>');
                echo('</td></tr>');
            }
                echo('</table>');     
        ?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Upload code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
    $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
    $filepath = "images/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO snapcodes (img_name,img_path,img_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?), '$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
  header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

After clicking the Upload button is image uploaded to the "images" folder, but no data are uploaded to the database. Tables are empty.

I would like to get table like this:

```
********************************************
   username | age | gender | uploaded image
 1.user     | 15  | male   | image         
 2.user2    | 14  | female | image     
********************************************
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Don't just define your query as a string and hope the query gnomes will come along and run it for you, *execute it*.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user-supplied `$_FILES` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @tadman both are good points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution.

The error was in the  tag. I used the action="upload.php" attribute, but upload.php cared only about uploading an image, not a recording of the entire form.

So I removed the action="upload.php" attribute and I put PHP ipmroved code from upload.php into the file that contains the function INSERT for entire form.

Thank you all for your advice and warnings :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to answer "the upload thing", as it is not the topic of the question. I am not commenting on code structuring, SQL injections, use of Czech to name variables, and other issues, either. See @tadman's comments.

As of JOIN, you join on IDs which are both autoincrement. It does not make much sense. You should define a column like `user_id` in `images` table and then use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.user_id
ORDER BY table1.ID
```